# A mysterious love letter

Tags: riddle

What is the number implied by the following love letter? And who wrote it?

> f+stdrlsdlts+mslt-mfl-sd

Comment: Wait I actually want to know the answer :P

Comment: @NL628 The code is musical solfege (d = do, r = re, etc., with '+' being sharp and '-' being flat), and the message is the main theme of Tchaikovsky's "Romeo and Juliet" (hence the "love letter"). As for the number, I realize that "the number implied" isn't very precise; I had "R + J = 18 + 10 = 28" in mind.